# Java summing numbers up weirdly

Tags: java

I keep getting this weird mistake. When I try to sum the user input on their grades, it sums them up like next to each other instead of an actual sum.

I realized the issue is with the `string` to `int` conversion, but I can't manage to understand how to fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sumCalculator {


    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Sum calculator v1.0");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number");
        String num1 = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        String num2 = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your third number");
        String num3 = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your fourth number");
        String num4 = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your fifth number");
        String num5 = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter you sixth (and last) number");
        String num6 = reader.nextLine();

        int numSumAddUp = Integer.parseInt (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 
                + num5 + num6);     
        System.out.println("The average of yours grades is" + 
                numSumAddUp / 6);

        reader.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: You should parse those strings to ints separately.

Comment: Looks to me like num1, num2, etc. are strings. So what does "42" + "15" do?

Comment: You need to parse every Input to string and then add them.

Comment: Explanation `num1 + num2` (where at least one is a String) is doing string concatenation (e,g, `"12" + "34"` results in the string `"1234"` (as Just one of terms must be a string, `"12" + 34` is also `"1234"`)

Comment: hint: for that *many* grades, I would suggest using a loop and array....

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your problem is here:

```
int numSumAddUp = Integer.parseInt (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 
        + num5 + num6);
```

Try parse them individually

```
int num1parsed = Integer.parseInt(num1);
int num2parsed = Integer.parseInt(num2);
int num3parsed = Integer.parseInt(num3);
int num4parsed = Integer.parseInt(num4);
int num5parsed = Integer.parseInt(num5);
int num6parsed = Integer.parseInt(num6);
```

and only then try to sum them:

```
int numSumAddUp = num1parsed + num2parsed + num3parsed + num4parsed + num5parsed + num6parsed;
```

Comment: ohhh i thought that if i like converted it once than it would like work, thank you :)

Comment: Basically what you did is concating the numbers so if first number is 4 and 2nd is 3 and 3rd is 5 then you tried to parse 435 as String act different from int when you use + sign.  if you like you can read more about it here  [Java String Manipulation: Functions and Methods with EXAMPLE](https://www.guru99.com/java-strings.html)

Comment: `prased`? Parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Use reader.nextInt to read each number. You will be able to add them without having to convert from string.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just used the `nextInt()` method of Scanner which does the parsing implicitly.

```java
int num1 = reader.nextInt();
int num2 = reader.nextInt();
System.out.println(num1 + num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Sum calculator v1.0");
        System.out.println("Enter your first number");
        int num1 = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        int num2 = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your third number");
        int num3 = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your fourth number");
        int num4 = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your fifth number");
        int num5 = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter you sixth (and last) number");
        int num6 = reader.nextInt();

        int numSumAddUp = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6;
        System.out.println(String.format("The average of yours grades is %d", numSumAddUp / 6));

        reader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have an answer there, but i will propose another way to parse all and sum in a short piece of code:

```
int numSumAddUp = Arrays.asList(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```